# HTML/JS: onblur function to see if a particular button is being pressed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have client side validation which puts a "value required" message on the screen if an HTML text-input field is empty during onblur. This works well except for the special case when the user hits this form's submit button.

Submitting a form with missing text fails server-side validation which brings up a more pronounced error message. My problem is that the on-blur message kicks on for a very brief moment before the new page is loaded.

It's not a functionality problem but it does look a bit unprofessional. EDIT: For clarity, I should mention that this function is launched from this html:

```
<span id="hname">Name:</span><br> 
<input type="text" id="name" onblur="field_val('#hname', this);" 
    class="contact" name="name" size="31">
```

The function itself is here:

```
function field_val(label_id, input_id)
{
    var input_text = $(input_id).val();     
    var label_text = $(label_id).html();

    /* Considering surrounding the code in this function
        with an if statement that will not execute in the case
        that a submit button with an id of "fsubmit" has been
        pressed in conjunction with the onblur event that 
        called this function in the first place */

    if (input_text == "")
    {
        if(label_text.indexOf("(required field)") == -1)    
            $(label_id).html(label_text + " (required field)");

        $(label_id).css("color", "red");
    }
    else
    {
        if(label_text.indexOf("(required field)") != -1)    
            $(label_id).html(label_text.substring(0, label_text.indexOf("(required field)")));

        $(label_id).css("color", "rgb(51,51,51)");
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't see an onblur in this code anywhere.

Comment: @developerwjk It's in the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing that comes to my mind is using the HTML5 `required` attribute:

```
<input type="text" class="abc" id="id123" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Required Field.')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')" required>
```

I am setting the default message to show 'Required Field'. This is tried and tested on all browsers. Works like a charm.

And also does not let you submit a form unless all `required` fields are filled out.